# Basic addition with Python, numbers don't add

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm pretty new to Python and I was trying to make a basic addition program.  Here is the source so far:

```
from os import system
import time

while True:
    system("cls")
    print "Number 1:"
    num1 = raw_input()
    system("cls")
    print "Number 2:"
    num2 = raw_input()
    system("cls")
    sum = num1 + num2
    print sum
    time.sleep(4)
```

It just puts num1 and num2 together instead of actually adding the numbers.  Like if I put 4 + 4 it'd do 44 instead of 8.  I understand WHY it does this I just want to know how to fix it.

Comment: cast the `raw_input` to an int `num1 = int(raw_input())`

Comment: `num1 = int(raw_input())` and `num2 = int(raw_input())` would get your job done, actually `raw_input()` returns a `String` and `+` operator performs concatenation, incase of `String`

Comment: Please, do your own research on stackoverflow and the web before posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are summing strings, which results in concatenation, while you want to treat the values as *numbers* instead. Convert the string to a number first.

Use the [`int()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) to convert to integer numbers, for example:

```
num1 = int(raw_input())
# ...
num2 = int(raw_input())
```